# Consulta MySQL utilizando JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Olá! Tenho o seguinte banco de dados:

[image: Modelagem escola]

Gostaria de fazer uma consulta onde eu consiga pesquisar por exemplo o professor x que está relacionado ao aluno y e z mas não o aluno w. Porém ao executar minhas consultas ele exibe o professor x relacionado tbm ao aluno w msm não constando a relação na tabela aluno_has_professor.

```
SELECT nomealuno, nomeprofessor FROM  aluno, professor as A
INNER JOIN aluno_has_professor as B ON (B.professor_idprofessor = A.idprofessor)
WHERE idprofessor = 2;
```

Por gentileza alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Um aluno só pode ter um professor ou pode vários?

Comment: Seu sql está selecionando tudo de aluno, vc tem que adicionar um join entre aluno e aluno_has_professor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta esta query:

```
SELECT 
    p.nomeprofessor,a.nomealuno 
from professor p
JOIN aluno_has_professor ap on p.idprofessor = ap.professor_idprofessor 
JOIN aluno a on a.idaluno = ap.aluno_idaluno
WHERE
p.nomeprofessor='Walmir'
```

ou pelo id

```
SELECT 
    p.nomeprofessor,a.nomealuno 
from professor p
JOIN aluno_has_professor ap on p.idprofessor = ap.professor_idprofessor 
JOIN aluno a on a.idaluno = ap.aluno_idaluno
WHERE
p.idprofessor ='2'
```

Comment: funcionou! muito obrigado!

Comment: ^^ fico feliz em ajudar espero que tenha entendido o que eu fiz.

Answer (score 3):

O seu erro se encontra nesse trecho:

```
FROM  aluno, professor as A
INNER JOIN aluno_has_professor as B ON (B.professor_idprofessor = A.idprofessor)
```

Acabou misturando duas formas de fazer select, utilizando INNER JOIN ou não.
Você realizar select de duas formas:

```
SELECT * FROM professor AS A 
INNER JOIN aluno_has_professor as B ON 
(B.professor_idprofessor = A.idprofessor)
```

Ou

```
SELECT * FROM professor AS A, aluno_has_professor as B 
WHERE B.professor_idprofessor = A.idprofessor
```

Sempre que utilizar mais que uma tabela você deve fazer o relacionamento entre elas e a diferença neste dois select's é que usando o INNER JOIN o relacionamento é feito após o ON e NÃO UTILIZANDO o INNER JOIN o relacionamento é feito após o WHERE.

No seu código você acabou misturando os dois jeitos ao montar seu select e ao colocar FROM aluno, professor e não colocar nenhum relacionamento entre as duas tabelas, você acaba trazendo tudo das duas tabelas. Por isso você trás o aluno W mesmo não sendo do professor com id = 2.
Você tem que interpretar da seguinte maneira, você tem uma tabela de alunos, uma tabela de professor e uma tabela de ligação entre as duas, o seu select deve ser feito da tabela aluno e da tabela professor para a tabela de ligação.

```
Select * from professor as A 
INNER JOIN aluno_has_professor as B ON (B.professor_idprofessor = A.idprofessor)
INNER JOIN aluno as C ON (B.aluno_idaluno = C.idaluno)
WHERE idprofessor = 2;
```

Não sei se os campos da tabela aluno estão corretos, mas a lógica é essa ligar suas duas tabelas na tabela de ligação.

Com isto ao escolher o professor de ID = 2, a tabela de ligação irá identificar apenas os alunos que são do professor ID = 2 na tabela de alunos.